# Count column with certain status

Tags: mysql, sql

My code below is working fine where im getting dependecy task. 
What I would like to count home many of these are in status "Completed". So in table notes column status: Example : notes.status = 'Completed'.

How can I add this to my code because I need to count those as well. 
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
     notes.id, notes.title, notes.status
FROM 
     notes, dependency 
WHERE 
     dependency.task_dependency = notes.id
     AND dependency.task = '7035' 
     ORDER BY notes.status = 'Not started' DESC
```

Comment: Do you want only a count of notes.status = 'Completed'? Or together with other infos (as notes.id, notes.title)?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I need them together with other info. Because it lists other notes.status like Not started, ongoing, but i just need to count the number of status completed

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax!  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

I think the following answers your question:

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, COUNT(*) as num_total,
       SUM(n.status = 'Not Completed') as num_not_completed,
FROM notes j JOIN
     dependency d
     ON d.task_dependency = n.id
WHERE e.task = '7035' 
GROUP BY n.id, n.title;
```